# Binding to Children does not work at run-time

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, binding

I am binding `Canvas` height to first children height so that it can be layed out properly, an example of layout:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Canvas Height="{Binding Children[0].ActualHeight , RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Red" />
    </Canvas>
    <TextBlock Text="Text" />
</StackPanel>
```

Without binding `Canvas.Height` value is `0`, so that the "Text" overlaps, with binding - text is under **in designer** (you can try it yourself).

However during **run-time** binding fails and text overlaps.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'Item[]' value (type 'UIElement') from 'Children' (type 'UIElementCollection'). BindingExpression:Path=Children[0].ActualHeight; DataItem='Canvas' (Name=''); target element is 'Canvas' (Name=''); target property is 'Height' (type 'Double') ArgumentOutOfRangeException:'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

Why? Can I have designer-time behavior at run-time?

I would like **not** to give child a `x:Name` and to bind using `ElementName`.

---

Here is better MCVE:

```
<ListBox>
    <TextBlock Text="1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1" />
    <TextBlock Text="2" />
    <TextBlock Text="3" />
    <Canvas Height="100">
        <TextBlock Canvas.Left="{Binding HorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollViewer}}"
                   Text="Frozen" />
    </Canvas>
    <TextBlock Text="4" />
    <TextBlock Text="5" />
</ListBox>
```

It works like this:

[image]

`"Frozen"` stays on screen disregards horizontal scrolling, while still treated as an item (vertical scrolling can move it away from view). This is possible to achieve due to `Canvas` properties: it has `0` height and width and doesn't cause any effect on layout. Note binding to `HorizontalOffset`.

Replace `Height="100"` with `Height="{Binding Children[0].ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`. It works in designer, but not at run-time!

Comment: What is the purpose of all that? Binding Width and Height can usually be avoided by using appropriate layout elements. E.g. replace the Canvas by a Grid or Border.

Comment: @Clemens, to create layout. Canvas will be a part of `ListViewItem` (to simulate frozen content, which stay disregards of horizontal scroll), but content is in datatemplate and *I though* I could autosize `Canvas` like this, otherwise `ListViewItem` is too small (`Canvas.Height` is `0` as I said).

Comment: But why "autosize" a Canvas, when other Panels already implement auto sizing?

Comment: `Canvas` is special. Any other container will affect `ListView` column/row, `Canvas` - doesn't. It allow to create content which *fly* on top of `ListViewItem`.

Comment: @Clemens, see edit please.

Comment: I think the problem is that the `Binding` at runtime is evaluated before the child actually exists. Why can't you use `ElementName` binding for this? It seems like a good fit

Answer (score 1):

As @MartinZikmund comment

> the problem is that the Binding at runtime is evaluated before the child actually exists

the second example can be rewritten as

```
<Canvas>
    <TextBlock Canvas.Left="{Binding HorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollViewer}}"
               Text="Frozen" />
    <Canvas.Height>
        <Binding Path="Children[0].ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
    </Canvas.Height>
</Canvas>
```

`Height` binding is set **after** content. Which makes it working at run-time.

Still the question why designer-time has no problems. Some wpf-magic I guess.

Comment: That's an interesting solution :-D !

Answer (score 1):

You could put this to a behavior:

```
private void Canvas_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Canvas)?.SetBinding(Canvas.HeightProperty, new Binding("Children[0].ActualHeight") { RelativeSource=new RelativeSource { Mode= RelativeSourceMode.Self } });
}
```

Comment: `Loaded` is triggered after xaml is fully processed (content should be availabe), so this should work too, useful to avoid full binding syntax. Thanks.